# gdal_rasterize of shapefile takes days?

Tags: gdal-rasterize

I'm trying to rasterize the "Decreasing land productivity" shapefile from https://wad.jrc.ec.europa.eu/geoportal, using:

`gdal_rasterize -3d -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -ts 43200 21600 ./lpd_int2.shp ./ldp_int2.tif`

(also tried without the COMPRESS=DEFLATE)
It has been running for 6 days and is only 40% completed.

Though the output is 43200x21600, this still seems like an excessively slow process. Is there some obvious thing I'm doing which is making it take too long?

```
$ ogrinfo -ro -al -listmdd lpd_int2.shp
INFO: Open of `lpd_int2.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: lpd_int2
Metadata domains:
  (default)
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=1919-09-29
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 226
Extent: (-179.999989, -55.600000) - (179.991667, 72.400000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
id_country: Real (33.15)
name_iso31: String (254.0)
iso3: String (254.0)
sqkm: Real (33.15)
lpd_sqkm: Real (33.15)
lpd_p: Real (33.15)
shape_leng: Real (33.15)
shape_area: Real (33.15)
OGRFeature(lpd_int2):0
  id_country (Real) = 3.000000000000000
  name_iso31 (String) = Afghanistan
  iso3 (String) = AFG
  sqkm (Real) = 643490.775693999952637
  lpd_sqkm (Real) = 52103.569999999999709
  lpd_p (Real) = 8.100000000000000
  shape_leng (Real) = 90294575.479599997401237
  shape_area (Real) = 80173734283.800003051757812
  MULTIPOLYGON  ...etc, etc...
```

Comment: The shapefile seems to contain extremely heavy geometries - only 226 polygons but the size of the .shp part of shapefile is 467 MB.

Comment: One of the monster multipolygons contains 516716 rings!

Comment: Oh. That seems like a lot. I'll start searching for how to simplify shapefile geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source dataset has huge multipolygons and GDAL has difficulties to deal with them. That applies also to ogr2ogr that cannot explode multipolygons into single part polygons with option `-explodecollections`. However, I found a reasonable simple workaround.

1. Convert the shapefile into SpatiaLite database with ogr2ogr

   `ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes lpd_int2.sqlite lpd_int2.shp -nlt promote_to_multi`
2. Explode the multipolygons into single part polygons with spatialite-gui. SpatiaLite has a special SQL function for the purpose as documented in http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

   > Will create a new out_table directly corresponding to in_table. The
   >   output table will be arranged in such a way that each row will always
   >   contain an elementary Geometry; so each time that a MULTI-type
   >   Geometry is found in the input table it will be split into mamy
   >   distinct rows. out_pk is the name to be set for the output Primary
   >   Key, and out_multi_id is the name to be set for a second column within
   >   the output table where to store the original Primary Key. The optional
   >   argument transaction determines if an internal SQL Transaction should
   >   be automatically started or not (the default setting if not explicitly
   >   overridden is TRUE).

   Syntax to use:

   `SELECT ElementaryGeometries('lpd_int2','GEOMETRY','exploded','id_1','id_2');`

   It took 2 min 30 seconds to create the new table with my laptop.
3. Run gdal_rasterize by using the exploded polygons from SpatiaLite as source data.

   `gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -co tiled=yes -ts 43200 21600 lpd_int2.sqlite -l exploded lpd_int2.tif`

   I modified your command a bit because the source shapefile nor the table of exploded polygons is not 3D and there are no Z coordinates to use as burn values. It took about 15 minutes to create a GeoTIFF and it looks like this in QGIS

[image]

**EDIT:**

The issue with ogr2ogr and -explodecollections is now also fixed in GDAL master, see https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1959.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I don't have a Windows system to run spatialite-gui, but was able to produce the same result using:

    ogrinfo ./lpd_int2.sqlite -sql "SELECT ElementaryGeometries('lpd_int2','GEOMETRY','exploded','id_1','id_2');"

Comment: I was about to ask how to 'explode polygons' from the console. Thanks for posting your solution DGentry, and also for the explanation, @user30184